# Accordion bounces to left when clicked

Tags: jquery, accordion

jQuery accordion bounces to the left when content iframe is loaded. I'm stumped.

Any suggestions?

I'm guessing it's something with the iframe sizing code.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, 
        active: false
    });
});
```

[**Accordion in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4q2c/)

Comment: It bumps because the page overflows on accordion open creating a scrollbar.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. Nothing I can do is there? Like change iframe size. I think it I tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounce is normal browser behaviour when a scroll-bar appears. In older browsers such as IE 7 (I think) the scroll-bar always used to be visible, just disabled when not needed. So no bounce would occur.

#### Adjusting the Overflow

You can still achieve that and use the `overflow` property to always have the scroll-bar visible even when not needed.

Just like the older browsers it disables the scroll-bar when not needed and enables it when it is needed. Hence, no bounce.

The following CSS would do that:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

---

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwQrf/) - Always show the scroll-bar

---

#### Adjusting the height

Another alternative would be to make the document a little taller then 100%, therefore you also have always the scroll-bar visible but it is always enabled.

You can add the following CSS for that:

```
html {
    height: 101%;
}
```

---

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/HTyw3/) - Using a larger HTML document

---

**DEMO 1** seems to be the more standard approach as it looks more like browsers used to look and the grayed out scroll-bar is not all that visible when disabled.

**DEMO 2** might be less favorable as, unlike the above option, a scroll-bar which is never disabled always seems to indicate scroll-able content, even when the content is not.

Using a JavaScript solution might work off course but is also much heavier and might be more tedious to maintain/update.

Answer (score 1):

Not really cool, but you can easly try some work around like this:

```
$(function(){ $('.ui-accordion-header').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active')){
         $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
         $('body').css('overflow','auto');
         },600);
        }
        });
        });
```

[working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/q4q2c/2/)

Comment: @sbaaaang: Using [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) hit the `TidyUp` button and it formats the code for you, making it readable. Copy it then from there to the answer. Currently it is very hard to eyeball the code and realise where what starts and ends.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yeah you know i'm just another lazy one :P, i tryed tidying up but the result it's the same you can check it by your own :/

Comment: not gonna work I need the outer scroll for whole page to be able to scroll and see bottom tabs when opened darn

Comment: @user2630503 so you definitly can't get what you want, imo, cause if you want to be scrollable you'll get jumping